# Не работает bootstrap tooltip с элементом у которого в стилях есть ::after

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

У элементов с такими стилями тултипы не показываются:

```css
li.active::after {
      content: "";
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
} 
li.active {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="list-inline">
   <li class="active" >
   <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="bottom" title="Proof">NotWork</span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Добавьте `z-index: -1;` для `li.active::after`

Пример

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

```css
li.active::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  z-index: -1;
}

li.active {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li class="active">
    <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="bottom" title="Proof">NotWork</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: спасибо, понял  что мне нужно дальше делать